# Return array of elements from multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I got a collection of companies that looks like this. I also want to merge other documents deals.
I need this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae993e"), 
    "locations" : [
        {
            "deals" : [
                {
                    "name" : "1", 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae9940")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "2", 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("562f868ce73962c626a16b15")
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "deals" : [
        {
            "name" : "3", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("562f86ebe73962c626a16b17")
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae993e"), 
    "locations" : [
        {
            "deals" : [
                {
                    "name" : "4", 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae9940")
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "deals" : []
}
```

To be like this:

```
{
    "deals": [{
        "name" : "1", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae9940")
    },{
        "name" : "2", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("562f868ce73962c626a16b15")
    },{
        "name" : "3", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("562f86ebe73962c626a16b17")
    },{
        "name" : "4", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae9949")
    }]
}
```

But I have only failed to do this. It seems like if I want all the deals to be grouped together into one array I should not use unwind since that create more documents because I only need to group once.
This is my attempt which does not work at all.

```
{
                "$project": {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "locations": 1,
                    "deals": 1
                }
            }, {
                "$unwind": "$locations"
            }, {
                "$unwind": "$locations.deals"
            }, {
                "$unwind": "$deals"
            }, {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": null,
                    "deals": { 
                        "$addToSet": "$locations.deals",
                        "$addToSet": "$deals"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first use filter your documents to reduce the size of documents to  process in the pipeline using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator. Then  we need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the "locations" array after that we  use the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator to reshape your documents. The `$cond` operator is used to return a single element array `[false]` if the `deals` field is empty array or the `deals` value because `$unwind`ing empty array will throw an exception. Of course the [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) operator does return an array of element that appear in the `locations.deals` array or the `deals` array. We then use the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) operator to filter out the `false` element from the merged array. We then need another [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage where we  deconstruct the `deals` array. From there we can easily [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "locations.0": { "$exists": true } } },
    { "$unwind": "$locations" }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "deals": { 
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$setUnion": [  
                     { "$cond": [
                         { "$eq" : [ { "$size": "$deals" }, 0 ] }, 
                         [false], 
                         "$deals"
                     ]},
                     "$locations.deals"
                ]}, 
                [false]
            ]
         }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$deals" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "deals": { "$addToSet": "$deals" }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{
        "_id" : null,
        "deals" : [
                {
                        "name" : "1",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae9940")
                },
                {
                        "name" : "2",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("562f868ce73962c626a16b15")
                },
                {
                        "name" : "3",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("562f86ebe73962c626a16b17")
                },
                {
                        "name" : "4",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("561637942d25a7644cae9940")
                }
        ]
}
```